# What is the correct Bitcoin.org wallet download?

Tags: lightning-network, bitcoin.org

anyone able to install the [Bitcoin Wallet](https://wallet.bitcoin.org/)?
Apple store is taking me to Bitcoin Wallet from COINiD, doesn't seem right?

1. Does the Bitcoin Wallet handle the Lightning Network?
2. Can the Bitcoin Wallet send random amounts or does it need a Lightning Invoice to pay with an exact amount?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the correct Bitcoin.org wallet download?

Bitcoin.org is not an official Bitcoin website, no website is. It long ago ceased to be run by the original developers and was taken over by others.  I suspect it no longer follows its original goals of impartiality.

You should choose wallet software carefully.

Comment: Worth noting as some may be unaware. This seems to be a useful URL for wallets https://walletscrutiny.com/ I'm looking for a self custody, Lightning, reproducible, can pay random amounts without an invoice wallet.